# tearDown not called after timeout in twisted trial?

Tags: python, testing, twisted, trial

I'm seeing an issue in my test suite in trial where everything works fine until I get a timeout. If a test fails due to a timeout, the tearDown function never gets called, leaving the reactor unclean which in turn causes the rest of the tests to fail. I believe tearDown should be called after a timeout, does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `tearDown()` should be called regardless of what happens in your test. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) for `tearDown()`:

> This is called even if the test method raised an exception

However, there is a catch. From the same documentation:

> This method will only be called if the setUp() succeeds, regardless of the outcome of the test method.

So it sounds like you perhaps start the reactor in `setUp()` and when it times out, this is preventing your `tearDown()` from running - the idea being that whatever you were trying to "set up" in `setUp()` was *not* successfully set up, so you do not want to try to tear it down. However, it would be hard to diagnose with certainty unless you provide the code of your `setUp` and `tearDown` methods, along with the code of any relevant tests.

Comment: Is there any way to tell if the setUp is failing? It looks like it's completing successfully and moving on to the test. Then it fails in the test and tearDown never gets called

Comment: Does the timeout raise an exception? If so you could try catching that exception. But it is hard to say without seeing the method. Could you add the code of your `setUp` method to your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather strange because on my box, the teardown executes even if a timeout occurs. The tests should stop running if the reactor is not in a clean state, unless you use the `--unclean-warnings` flag. Does the test runner stop after the timeout for you? What version of Python and Twisted are you running?

As a side note, if you need to run a unique teardown for a specific test function, there's a very convenient [`addCleanup()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html#cleaning-up-after-tests) callback. It comes in handy if you need to cancel callback, LoopingCall, or callLater functions so that the reactor isn't in a dirty state. `addCleanup` returns a `Deferred` so you can just chain callbacks that perform an adhoc teardown. It might be a good option to try if the class teardown isn't working for you.

PS

I've been so used to writing "well behaved" Twisted code, I don't even recall how to get into an unclean reactor state :D I swear I'm not bragging. Could you provide me a brief summary of what you're doing so that I could test it out on my end?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I'll put this here in case it's helpful to anyone else in the future.

I was returning a deferred from the test that had already been called (as in, deferred.callback had been called), but it still had an unfinished callback chain. From what I can see in the trial code here https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/twisted-16.5.0/src/twisted/trial/_asynctest.py#L92, the reactor is crashed when this happens, which explains why the tearDown doesn't get called. The solution for me was to return a deferred from the offending tests that does not have a callback chain that lives for a long time (it's callbacks do not return deferreds themselves).